# Alert on due date with only Three-state workflow

Tags: alert, expiration

I don't know if this is possible. I have a column that calculates number of days based on an date of expiration column. For example, a contract is ending on July 1 2018 and today is June 1 2018, the column should then display 30 days. I have been trying to make an email alert based on the number of days, 30, 60, 90.

I have tried using Calculated Value in Choice Field, but it doesn't recognize other fields outside of its own. I have also tried using Calculated Field, but Three-state Workflow doesn't recognize other fields apart from Choice Field.

I don't have access to other workflow and designer so... any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the OOTB Disposition workflow?  Check out the section titled Disposition in this [link](http://kimfrehe.com/category/sharepoint/).  You can use the Disposition workflow in conjunction with an Information Management Policy Settings.

Comment: O, I have access to Disposition Approval workflow and Information Management Policy Settings. Thanks!

Comment: Information Management Policy Settings only have + (plus) years, months and days in the future. It cannot alert user of 3 months before it ends. :(

Comment: See Answer below.  This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that you can use any date field in an Information Management Policy - as you see in my screehshot, I have 4 date fields to choose from, I can trigger the workflow off any of these date fields.

All you need to do is to create a `NewDate` field which is e.g. 90 days less than the Expiration Date.

As for populated your `NewDate` field, you could try using a Sharepoint Designer Workflow to SET the date in the `NewDate` field.  We'll call this workflow SetReminderDate.

Assuming that the `ExpirationDate` field is always populated (configure it as a REQUIRED field so it always has a value).  Then the SetReminderDate workflow can be triggered on item creation - configure it to SET a value of `ExpirationDate-90 days`.

Then configure the Information Management Policy to run off the `ExpirationDate` value.  The Disposition workflow in your IMP will be triggered from the `ExpirationDate` field.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access/rights to Sharepoint Designer. I did something similar. Since each contract has its own expiration date, I had to create a calculated field with =expiration-180. And just found out that Information Management Policy doesn't see calculated field with date...

Comment: From your example, I have to input 90 days less manually?

Comment: If you don't have Sharepoint Designer, ask your IT dept to do this for you.  Otherwise you'll need to use Powershell, I can't help with that.  With a Sharepoint Designer Workflow you can use it to copy the CalculatedFieldValue to a new number field which I will call ExpirationMinus90Days.  The IMP will be able to use the number field, but not a calculated field.  OR you will need to manually copy the CalculatedFieldValue to the ExpirationMinus90Days field.